# Selecting an element with different value but similar id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can you select an  element with value 2 using jQuery, if they all have same name and id?

```
 <input type="radio" id="store" name="store" value="1">
    <input type="radio" id="store" name="store" value="2">
     <input type="radio" id="store" name="store" value="3">
```

jQuery that didn't work:

```
$('#store:input[type="radio", value="2"]').html();
```

Comment: __You should only have one of each id__ - you should do what you're trying to do with classes instead...

Comment: Sometimes you can't control the HTML. In those cases, you can use @reski's solution.

Comment: I know, but I am trying to create an autofill for some website, and the developer there named everything in such way.

Comment: @FrankModica except it doesn't work - I just tried it and jQ returned no elements.

Comment: Ops, Sorry!, @sam you were right!

Comment: @Sam Works for me if I do `input#store`

Comment: @FrankModica yep, I mentioned it in a comment below the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's selector engine can't handle it, but you can use then native `querySelector` instead, after you fix your selector.

```js
const v = document.querySelector('input#store[type="radio"][value="2"]').outerHTML;

console.log(v);
```

```html
 <input type="radio" id="store" name="store" value="1">
 <input type="radio" id="store" name="store" value="2">
 <input type="radio" id="store" name="store" value="3">
```

`querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` don't care about the HTML requirement of unique IDs. They fetch all matches on the page.

Also, `.html()` didn't make sense for an `input`, so I printed its `.outerHTML instead`.

Comment: Thanls @rock star, where I can get more resource on selectors ?

Comment: @feedammo: Pretty much any CSS selector tutorial, since they use CSS selectors.

Comment: Thank You very much @rock star, you saved me a lot of time. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You can't—there should only be one instance of any given #id on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [multiple attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/).

This should work:
$('#store:input[type="radio"][value="2"]').html();

Comment: For some reason `#store:input` only returns the first element for me, so it doesn't select it - `input#store[type='radio'][value='2']` works fine though